# Why does this code continuously print newlines?

Tags: c++, loops, io, iostream, istream-iterator

```
 int row,column;

 for (;;) {

    cin >> rows >> columns;

    if (!rows && !columns) break;

    vector<char> dots(rows * columns);

    copy(istream_iterator<char>(cin), istream_iterator<char>(), dots.begin());

    // process vector

    copy(dots.begin(), dots.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));

    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Is the variable `row`, or `rows`? C++ doesn't automagically fix up pluralization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `istream_iterator` reaches its end when an input error or end-of-file occurs (buffer overrun which may happen with your vector doesn't count :) ).

Once `cin` is in error or EOF state, all subsequent input operations will fail (unless you `cin.clear();` the state) and the code ends up just displaying newlines.

---

It's a bit unclear whether this is what you actually want. Perhaps you just want to read `rows*column` characters (perhaps discarding newlines in the input).

Comment: I think you are right, just needs to add a cin.clear(). I am guessing that the confusion about newlines occurs only because of the lack of feedback. Simply output the value of rows and colums would show that it reuses the same first values every times, but since dots is reset, it doesn't output anything.

Comment: adding cin.clear() fixed it, thanks. I also fixed the potential buffer overrun by passing a back_inserter as 3rd parameter to std::copy

Answer (score 3):

Ummm, you have a `cout << '\n';` inside that loop... so it'll print a `newline` for each time it goes through the loop.

Comment: yeah but it prints only newlines after it prints the contents of the vector once...what i want to do is to read new data each time it loops and print it

Comment: @RaouL: Can you post sample input and output data (both expected and what you are getting for output).

Comment: I disagree, `for(;;)` is *defined* to be infinite, but `while(1)` is arguably just an abuse of a conditional loop (and may emit warnings, which can be annoying).

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise your variables, row and column (probably to 0). It's a good habit to get in to.

Comment: It's more important to check that input into them succeeded.  Unless you actually need such initial values for something like ints, adding a dummy value just hides that you're maybe using it uninitialized at some point (which might be a warning from the compiler).

Comment: Exactly, in this case cin fails after the second iteration (because of the lack of cin.clear()) and thus the code reuses the same old values of rows and columns. Just reset them to 0 each time before trying to reading the input would prevent such bug.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the:

```
for(;;)
```

Which stands for 'do this forever' combined with the fact that the rows and columns may never be both set to zero with cin.

Try typing in zeroes for the cin input and it might end.

Also write:

```
cout << endl;
```

That is just what I do because I like flushing buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't really answer your question, but you can combine your two `copy` into one, as

```
copy(istream_iterator<char>(cin), istream_iterator<char>(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this line:

```
copy(istream_iterator<char>(cin), istream_iterator<char>(), dots.begin());
```

is doing what you want it to do... I'm not sure if you can use copy with cin in this way, as I don't think `istream_iterator<char>()` will be an iterator pointing to the last element you want to read. Is this from an example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe intend to initialize your row and column to some value and then decrement them or something?  As it stands, sometimes your code will continue forever, sometimes it'll exit on the first run of the loop before it even does anything interesting.